# how to scroll my page with easing effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to scroll my page with easing effect?
  i want when i will click on menu then its id section call by scrolling with easing effect

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myNavbar" data-offset="0">
        <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
        <div class="container">
           <h1 class="navbar-brand align" href="#">ashish</h1>
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-  

target="#navbarCollapse">


                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button> 
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#homesection">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ourServices">What i do?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

thanks in advance plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
<a href="#Portfolio" onClick="scrollTo('Portfolio', event)">Portfolio</a>
```

Section:

```
<div id="Portfolio">....</div>
```

JS:

```
function scrollTo(element, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('html, body').animate({ 'scrollTop' : $('#' + element).offset().top + 'px' }, 1000);
}
```

You will need jQuery for this.

Cheers